# C header file include error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, header

Hopefully this is a straightforward question...  Here's my process to reproduce this issue.  First I create my source file:

```
bash $ cat t.c
#include "t.h"

int main()
{
  ABC abc;
}
```

Then I create my corresponding header file:

```
bash $ cat t.h
#ifdef _T_H
#define _T_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct abc { 
  int a;
} ABC;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Then, I try to compile it:

```
bash $ gcc -o t t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5: error: ‘ABC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
t.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
t.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
t.c:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘abc’
```

What is going on?  If I use 'struct abc' instead of 'ABC' as the type in t.c, then it does compile.  Why aren't the typedefs working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
#ifndef _T_H
#define _T_H
```

I happened to notice this because the `_T_H` didn't line up, and my subconscious brain knew it should.

Comment: Bingo.  Wow, yeah, that one little 'n' screwing everything up.  Well hopefully somebody else who has that problem will see this thread :)

Comment: BTW, do not use things starting with underscore, or containing a double underscore, for your header guards. Such names are reserved for use by the standard library implementation. Just `T_H` does the trick just fine.